# Add/remove CRON action depending on variable

Tags: filters, actions, wp-cron

I've hooked a function on to a CRON job called `'job_manager_check_for_expired_jobs'`, and I want it to run based on the value of a variable `$create_sitemap`.  The value is true by default, but can be changed by a filter.

The problem is that if I use the site and then then change the filter to be false later, the hook still runs as though the variable is true - so the action isn't being removed.

Code I'm using is here, any help would be appreciated!

```
    // Check the WPJM plugin exists
    if( is_plugin_active( 'wp-job-manager/wp-job-manager.php') ){

    // Generate sitemap by default
    $create_sitemap = true;

    // Add filter so that users turn off the sitemap generation if they want
    if( has_filter('sitemap_filter_func') ) {
        $create_sitemap = apply_filters('sitemap_filter_func', $create_sitemap);
    }

    // If we want to ping Google
    if( $create_sitemap == true ){

        // Create the CRON job
        add_action( 'job_manager_check_for_expired_jobs', 'generate_sitemap' );

    } else {

        // Remove the CRON job to update the sitemap
        remove_action( 'job_manager_check_for_expired_jobs', 'generate_sitemap' );

    }

    }

function generate_sitemap() {

$sitemap = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$sitemap .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';

// Get a query of all jobs that are available
$all_jobs = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'job_listing', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

// Add the URL and last modified time (in GMT) to the sitemap
foreach( $all_jobs->posts as $post ){

  $sitemap .= '<url>';
  $sitemap .= '<loc>' . get_the_permalink( $post->ID ) . '</loc>';
  $sitemap .= '<lastmod>' . date( 'c', strtotime( $post->post_modified_gmt ) ) . '</lastmod>';
  $sitemap .= '</url>';

}

$sitemap .= '</urlset>';

// Write the sitemap to yoursite.com/job-sitemap.xml
$fp = fopen(ABSPATH . 'job-sitemap.xml', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $sitemap);
fclose($fp);

}
```

Example filter being used:

```
add_filter( 'sitemap_filter_func', 'hide_the_sitemap');
function hide_the_sitemap( $create_sitemap ){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where are you using/putting this conditional code?

Comment: It's in the index file of a custom plugin.

Comment: Maybe you can try prioritising your `add_action` and `remove_action` hooks? Also, does your `generate_map` function initiates any scheduled event or does it contain code for generating sitemap only?

Comment: Can you post a full sample code we can use to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Updated to show all the code used - it's an extension for the [WP Job Manager](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/) plugin for further reference.

Comment: I've tried adding a priority of 1 to both the `add_action` and `remove_action` hooks and it's the same result unfortunately.

Comment: I am not sure why this is not working, but alternatively, you could add the conditional tag to your code inside `generate_sitemap` so if `$create_sitemap` is `true` run the code for sitemap generation, otherwise not.

Comment: Thank Junaid, that works for what I'm looking for! Still confused as to why the add_action / remove_action parts don't work though.

Comment: I have posted an answer based on our conversation, please mark that as the solution. I'll be debugging the hook issue, if I figure it out, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the `remove_action` isn't working because by the looks of your code, it should. Alternatively, you can add the conditional logic to your `generate_sitemap()`

```
function generate_sitemap() {

    global $create_sitemap;

    if ( $create_sitemap ) return false;

    $sitemap = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    $sitemap .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';

    // Get a query of all jobs that are available
    $all_jobs = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'job_listing', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

    // Add the URL and last modified time (in GMT) to the sitemap
    foreach( $all_jobs->posts as $post ){
        $sitemap .= '<url>';
        $sitemap .= '<loc>' . get_the_permalink( $post->ID ) . '</loc>';
        $sitemap .= '<lastmod>' . date( 'c', strtotime( $post->post_modified_gmt ) ) . '</lastmod>';
        $sitemap .= '</url>';
    }

    $sitemap .= '</urlset>';

    // Write the sitemap to yoursite.com/job-sitemap.xml
    $fp = fopen(ABSPATH . 'job-sitemap.xml', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $sitemap);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Make sure `$create_sitemap` is accessible within the function.